# Convention System for Hindustani Music

Tags: pitch, indian-classical

In Western Music, we find that A4 has a particular frequency that is 440Hz. So it has only one sound. All the modes and scales are defined in terms of intervals. However, we find in Hindustani Music that all the raagas and thaats are defined in terms of interval. However, it seems that there is no convention. For example, Sa maybe C or C# or D or whatever of the 12 notes. That's why instruments are said to be tuned to B or C. Thus the Indian Instruments depends on Western for tuning, and giving a particular sound a particular name. But back in the old days, when the world was not seeing a globalized picture, this should not have been the case. **Then what is the system of Hindustani Music where we give a name to a particular Swara?** After all 'Sa', 'Re', 'Komal Re' etc. are all intervals.

NOTE: By saying "Thus the Indian Instruments depends on Western for tuning" I do not mean to disrespect Hindustani Music as I am Indian too.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting, but I did not see any question...

Comment: @Tom Sorry I typed a '.' instead of a'?' and also to make things more interesting I made the question bold

Comment: As I understand it, the question is "What's the history of the pitch standardization in Hindustani music, especially at times before it was defined in reference to Western standards." An intriguing question and I don't know the answer, but I imagine it's been researched before. Have you tried any initial research?

Comment: Also, note: Western music wasn't always standardized to A = 440! Before about the 19th century, it might be higher or lower in different times and places. See [this book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_History_of_Performing_Pitch/3Vwh0PZ3EuMC?hl=en&gbpv=0). I imagine the same is true in Indian history; earlier than a certain point I imagine "Sa" might have been a different frequency in one place than in another, if only slightly different. By the way, I don't know enough about *current* tuning practices! Could you please explain a bit more about how pitch is currently standardized?

Comment: It's not a scholarly source, but [this page by an importer of harmoniums](https://www.musiciansmallusa.com/a440-tuning-demystifed/) confirms that notion, or suggests that reference pitch has been non-standardized even much more recently. I guess it's always true that everyone tunes to the instrument that's the hardest to tune! Even today in Western music, if a small ensemble plays with a piano that is accidentally at 438, they'll tune down to match it. Beware of the assertion that Western pitch became standardized to allow large orchestras to play together. ...

Comment: ... The first orchestra, arguably, was in 1607, and there was still variation in the reference pitch for centuries to come.

Comment: @AndyBonner, thanks for the explanation. I had done a lot of research on this topic, but it had not helped so I did not include it. Secondly, as you say that A is not always standardized to 440 Hz, but varied from place to place I understand. But in Western Music the 'Sa' basically is the root, 'Komal Re' is the m2, 'Tivra Ma' is the tritone etc. But imagine a system which is going just on the basis of these intervals to define scales and modes.

Comment: For the page u provided, it still relies on the system of western to tune the instrument. Yes a music system should have system of intervals but how can it possibly go on without the system where each swara do not have a particular frequency. I hope u got it. And a big thanks for the different information u provided me.

Comment: @SarbanBhattacharya - Responding to "But imagine a system which is going just on the basis of these intervals to define scales and modes." - that is exactly how types of scales and modes are defined. For example, step sizes for a major scale are always WWHWWWH. Tonics aren't determined until later. Heck, for some symmetric scales such as the whole tone scale and the chromatic scale, **there is no clear tonic**.

Comment: @Dekkadeci, I understand, but that is just the interval. Then for example, two guitarists are performing, and they do not know the concept of A,B,C,D etc.. but just the intervals. So things will be like one is playing in A major and another in B major say. Things would be messy without this standardization. With the standardization, they know their key and they play it fluently, I Hope u got it :)

Comment: The notion that "*Sa* is always the root, but might be a different pitch frequency" is analogous to the Western notion of "[moveable *do*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge#Movable_do_solf%C3%A8ge)." It's mostly used as a teaching aid, though, and there is still an underlying expectation of a fixed and standardized reference pitch. (Confusingly, many countries use "fixed *do*" as that fixed way of naming notes, i.e. C is *do* no matter what key you're in.)

Comment: By the way, I think we still need some edits to make the question clear. Am I right that you're looking mainly for history—how pitch used to be described without reference to Western systems? (I think the answer will be that it wasn't standardized, just as Western practice wasn't for centuries.) Or are you looking for an idea of something to use *today* to speak of fixed pitch in a standardized but non-Western way?

Comment: @AndyBonner, I think I would be benefitted if get the answer to both. By non-Western way, I specifically mean the Hindustani. If you edit it, making things more appropriate, I would be very pleased.

Comment: When multiple musicians got together, they made sure to adjust their tuning to match each other in some way that was determined at the time. This is true for the history of ensembles in both Europe and South Asia and elsewhere. When fixed tuning instruments were involved (like organs in Europe) everyone tuned to the fixed pitch instruments. Fixed pitch ensembles (like Balinese gamelan) had to be carefully crafted to match. In Europe, easier to tune instruments adjusted to match harder to tune ones, which is why oboe became a tuning reference.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Can u please provide the answer w.r.t indian music?